# Не удаляет запись по вложенному запросу

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Я столкнулся с проблемой удаления строк по вложенному запросу, а если быть точнее, то в одной хранимке выполняется две операции удаления, и больше всего, я думаю, что сначала выполняется та, которая без вложенного запроса, а вторая уже не имеет необходимого значения.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `RemoveStudent`(
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
id CHAR(36)
)
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT Count(IdStudent) FROM GroupeStudent WHERE GroupeStudent.IdStudent = id) = 0
    THEN
    call RemoveCourseGroupe((SELECT GroupeStudent.IdGroupe FROM GroupeStudent WHERE GroupeStudent.IdStudent = id));
    END IF;
    DELETE FROM Student WHERE Student.Id = id;
END
```

Comment: Какое сообщение об ошибке выводится? Или просто не удаляется?

Comment: Нет, порядок операций нарушаться не может. Проверяйте свою процедуру RamoveCourseGroupe на то, что она выполняет то что ожидается и что на вход ей поступает ожидаемое значение

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема была в логике. Необходимо было переписать сам запрос.

```
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT Count(gs.IdStudent) FROM GroupeStudent 
        INNER JOIN GroupeStudent as gs ON gs.IdStudent = id) = 1)
    THEN
    call RemoveCourseGroupe((SELECT GroupeStudent.IdGroupe FROM GroupeStudent WHERE GroupeStudent.IdStudent = id));
    END IF;
    DELETE FROM Student WHERE Student.Id = id;
END
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, это ответ на ваш собственный вопрос?

Comment: да, просто не авторизировался изначально:)